# Stage vs Gazebo

Tags: ros, matlab, gazebo, simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Users:

I would like to know the pros and cons between Stage and Gazebo. Is there any document where I can find out?

Thanks!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211328/stage-vs-gazebo/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-06-15

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Stage is a 2D simulator and Gazebo is a 3D simulator. You can read about each here:

- Stage: http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/index.php?src=stage
- Gazebo: http://gazebosim.org/

Gazebo is more mature and has been/is under active development. The trade off is most simply put as: Gazebo will take more work and learning to setup, but is higher fidelity and has more features. Stage is simpler to setup, but is older, lower fidelity, and lacks many of the features and integrations of Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7